# My laptop refuses to work without the battery

Tags: laptop, battery

I work on 3d projects.

For 20 Minutes, everything is ok.

Then the battery flickers and turns red before switching off, even though it is connected to the charger.

Then I removed the battery, but the Laptop stays on for about 7 minutes then switches off.

I asked the service department about this, they answered a crazy thing;
That this laptop can't work without the battery.

*I dont want the battery*

I want to go on with my work in my house not in the park.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would try a new power adapter. Your adapter doesn't seem to be delivering enough power.

Comment: I work with many different laptops over a hundred different models in a month and i can say i have only seen one (some foreign manufacturer i have never heard of)  that has not been able to boot without a battery. Something like the design required the battery to complete the circuit so i'm just saying it is possible but very very rare.  Do what DrZoo suggested and see if a new supply makes a difference.

Comment: What laptop is this? What power supply are you using? Many laptops work poorly without a battery because the power supply can't increase the current fast enough to maintain voltage when the CPU/GPU suddenly increases its demand for power.

Answer (score 1):

> For 20 Minutes, everything is ok.
>
> Then the battery flickers and turns red before switching off, even though it is connected to the charger.
>
> Then I removed the battery, but the Laptop stays on for about 7 minutes then switches off.

Most likely you have a bad power brick. It is also possible that the power-input circuitry on the latop is bad.

I would start by replacing the power brick as this is usually relatively cheap and simple.

> I asked the service department about this, they answered a crazy thing; That this laptop can't work without the battery.

That would be very unusual for a laptop (though it is common for phones/tablets).

Comment: My laptop has a gurranty for 2 years,but because of the unusaual behavior of the seller ...I decided to open the laptop and remove the battery on my account.I know this end the guarranty witch is fake indeed.I'll try another adaptor and soon I am going send you feed back.Thanks a lot for your serious and quick response

Comment: Now i decide to send it to  Asus service point while i still have garanty

Comment: Oh my God.unbelievable thing.Finally,its solved .The battery charges forever so ,we have to remove it.But it still exists.Now we go to device manager and disable both 1.Microsoft AC Adapto 2.Microsoft ACPI Compliant Control Method Battery.Then the battery will never be resposible for the main power which affect the whole laptop .That's it.Tschüß.

Comment: Of course i forget to say 1 and 2 in device managet under the item:Batteries